# New site top bar missing from chat

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, top-bar

If you go to <strike>[chat.stackexchange.com](https://chat.stackexchange.com/)</strike> any page on stackexchange.com the old top bar is still in use. This makes me sad since I find the [new site header/top bar](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/a-new-top-bar-for-stack-exchange/) to be far superior.

It only seems fair that the main domain should also have the top bar designed to unify all Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: ~ eta 2 weeks...